# Facebook AMP video on samsung default browser

Tags: facebook, video, browser, amp-html

I have a iframe facebook video that work perfectly everywhere but samsung default browser.

it's on an AMP website version : 
https://kech24.com/%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%88-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%84%D9%83-%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B3-%D9%8A%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%89-%D8%A3%D8%B1%D8%B6-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%B7%D9%86.html

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Even on AMP project official website, it's not working : https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-facebook

Comment: Probably not much anyone here can do about that ... I would suggest you file a bug report with Facebook.